# Can't get user google account gender and birthday fields with google People API. (Using OAuth2client)

Tags: node.js, flutter, oauth-2.0, google-signin, google-people-api

I am implementing authentication with google in my mobile flutter app. I get the access_token in my app, and then I send it to backend which is written with Node.js. And thene I need to fetch user basic info + birthday and gender. In Google Cloud Platform console I did all configs, I added certain scopes,**'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read',          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read',**.   I enabled Google People API. But I still can not get birthday and gender. Here is backend part from.

```
const token =
  "HARDCODED_ACCESS_TOKEN";

var google = require("googleapis").google;
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2();

oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  access_token: token,
  scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read",
});

var oauth2 = google.oauth2({
  auth: oauth2Client,
  version: "v2",
});

oauth2.userinfo.get(function (err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(res.data);
  }
});
```

And here what I got in response.

[image]

I tried almost everything, but still couldn't get gender and birthday.

Comment: Is this all the code you're using? People API is not used in the code you provided. Can you clarify this?

Comment: If a am not wrong, for getting user basic info, gender, birthday, etc., you need to enable People API in your GCP, and use it. So in my case i think behind the scenes it uses People API. But do you have another better and more working method? I'll be glad to know.

Comment: (1) The `userinfo` endpoint you are using is not part of People API, these are two different API's and it's not "using it behind the scenes", (2) Are you sure you added this information (gender, birthday) to your account? `userinfo` endpoint should retrieve the `gender` information at least, but that's not part of the response you are getting, which makes me think it's not specified in your account, (3) If you want to retrieve `birthday`, you'll need to use People API. I can provide an answer explaining how to do this, but first please consider clarifying the issues I mentioned.

Comment: Firstly thanks you for the answer. Yes if you mean to provide info in my google account, yes I did it, and I also made it public. But still no result. Do you know another way of fetching user data with access_token ?

Comment: How did you retrieve this access_token? Having it hardcoded is definitely not the preferred OAuth flow.

Comment: Noo, I get it from my flutter app. If you are familiar with flutter, I use "google_sign_in" package for it. I get it from google, and then I send it to backend, and then from backend I need to retrieve user data for signing up. Is it bad approach? Or if I did something that is not good or is not good practice please let me know. I will be very grateful to you :)

Comment: You downloaded credentials from your GCP project, and then use these credentials to retrieve your access_token, right?

Comment: Yes. I retrieve the access_token from my mobile app, and then send it to the server. And already from the server, I need to get all user info and store it to my db. Is it good approach for "authenticating with google" ? Thank you in advance for helping.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't noticed. I'll take a look :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get information about `gender` and `birthdays` from the authenticated user, you can call People API's [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) with `resourceName=people/me` and `personFields=genders,birthdays`:

```
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  access_token: token,
});
const service = google.people({version: 'v1', auth: oauth2Client});
service.people.get({
  resourceName: 'people/me',
  personFields: 'genders,birthdays'
}, (err, res) => {
  // Do your thing
});
```

#### Notes:

- You didn't provide the code for most of the authentication process, but please note that the scopes have to be provided before retrieving the `access_token`, since the access token depends on those scopes. Also, I'd suggest you to set a `refresh_token`, since the `access_token` will expire in an hour. For more information about the OAuth process, please take a look at the [Node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/nodejs).
- It is assumed that both `genders` and `birthdays` are added to the authenticated user's account.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Right now I am working on another project, but tomorrow I will try what you provided. If it works, I will mark it as solved :)

Comment: I'm sorry, because of being busy, I can not try this solution right now, but I will mark it as solved. If I have questions in future, I will let you know. Thank you.