# Laravel Socialite, Login with Google in mobile App - userFromToken

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I am trying to implement Laravel social login with google (API for mobile APP), but I am stuck with scopes. No matter how I try, I cannot access the gender and date of birth.

I am creating access_token here:
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground

with selected and authorised API's:

```
email, profile, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read
```

and then in Laravel trying to get user data. Here is my code:

```
$scopes = [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read',
        ];

        $provider_user = Socialite::driver($sanitizedData['provider'])
            ->scopes($scopes)->userFromToken($sanitizedData['token']);
```

I receive id, name, email, avatar, nickname etc... but no gender and birthdate

Comment: You may need to use the resulting token to call a separate API. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67468142/cant-get-user-google-account-gender-and-birthday-fields-with-google-people-api